# How do I crossfilter 2 dc.js SeriesChart?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to creating visualizations with dc.js and I am looking to create 2 dc series chart where the second graph is filtered by clicking on the first graph. The second series graph (school graph) should display the different schools of that university e.g. Faculty of Engineering according to the university chosen (university graph). Currently, I am unable to click on the university graph for filtering and I don't know where I am going wrong.

Here is the link to the js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vfp7bdat/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- d3 cdn -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- crossfilter cdn -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-nlO6OGj6wb0uu/thpSry7qFal63hfhCLExpWxYomYB3tBznqWmKggsDHNHSLjnVaoade9tv/rErN498NSzwBnA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- dc cdn -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.2.3/dc.js"
      integrity="sha512-uIQEG7zDRB1dlmHnSs8pw8Mz3kiC1qdOxGnJyeTFNcYJIl60ITabMIxk3MQyzYx+7SfJitz3FVp6ySUwHPzwSQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.2.3/style/dc.css"
      integrity="sha512-ZCK4qcVpG4m3G6VG2CWs5Tl870Xn9xhT3SWJLmbsbTfU9/hzyZDeCzyLpjsCc27YxlDi19URyKlY+h4cQIifig=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- reductio cdn -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reductio/1.0.0/reductio.js"
      integrity="sha512-NGAPJvYQee6VfMDfMRjqWxzcKHXuk1mrEqlc+D8VumYz00Kn9a0/fRMk8zoyRA+QZXRJJQFNOuyh+h1gJc49Yg=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="uni">
      <strong>University</strong>
      <span class="reset" style="display: none"
        >Selected: <span class="filter"></span
      ></span>
      <a
        class="reset"
        href="javascript:uniChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();"
        style="display: none"
        >reset
      </a>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="school">
      <strong>School</strong>
      <span class="reset" style="display: none"
        >Selected: <span class="filter"></span
      ></span>
      <a
        class="reset"
        href="javascript:schoolChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();"
        style="display: none"
        >reset
      </a>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var uniChart = new dc.SeriesChart("#uni");
      var schoolChart = new dc.SeriesChart("#school");

      var data = d3
        .csv("cleaned_graduate-employment-survey-ntu-nus-sit-smu-suss-sutd.csv")
        .then(function (data) {
            // remove na value
            data = data.filter(function(d){
                if (isNaN(d["employment_rate_overall"])){
                    return false
                }
                d["employment_rate_overall"] = parseFloat(d["employment_rate_overall"]);
                return true
            })
          var ndx = crossfilter(data);
          // var all = ndx.groupAll();


          var uniDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return [d.university, d.year];
          });   
          var schoolDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){
            return [d.school, d.year];
          })
          var test = ndx.dimension(function(d){
            return d.university;
          })


          var yearDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.year;
          });
          var minDate = new Date(yearDim.bottom(1)[0].year);
          var maxDate = new Date(yearDim.top(1)[0].year);
          
          // group by employment rate
          var uniGroup = uniDim.group();
          var schoolGroup = schoolDim.group();

          var empRateReducer = reductio()
            .avg(function (d) {
              return parseFloat(d["employment_rate_overall"]);
            });
          empRateReducer(uniGroup);
          empRateReducer(schoolGroup);
          
          console.log(schoolGroup.all());

          uniChart
            .width(900)
            .height(500)
            .chart(function(c) { return new dc.LineChart(c).curve(d3.curveCardinal).renderDataPoints({radius: 5, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.0}); })
            .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
            .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([80, 100]))
            .brushOn(false)
            .yAxisLabel("Employment Rate (%)")
            .xAxisLabel("Year")
            .elasticX(true) 
            .elasticY(false)
            .dimension(uniDim)
            .group(uniGroup)
            .clipPadding(10)
            .mouseZoomable(false)
            .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
            .keyAccessor(function(d) {return new Date (d.key[1]);})
            .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value.avg;})
            .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(320).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(700));
          uniChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return `${d}%`;});
          uniChart.margins().left += 40;

          schoolChart
            .width(900)
            .height(500)
            .dimension(schoolDim)
            .group(schoolGroup)
            .elasticX(true)
            .elasticY(false)
            .brushOn(false)
            .yAxisLabel("Employment Rate (%)")
            .xAxisLabel("Year")
            .clipPadding(10)
            .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
            .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([80, 100]))
            .chart(function(c) { return new dc.LineChart(c).curve(d3.curveCardinal).renderDataPoints({radius: 5, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.0});; })
            .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
            .keyAccessor(function(d) {return new Date (d.key[1]);})
            .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.avg;})
            .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(320).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(700))
            //  .data(function (group) {
            //      return group.top(10);
            //    });

          dc.renderAll();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for making a fiddle to demonstrate your issue. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. (Both charts are blank.) However I notice that both charts have `.brushOn(false)`. This [disables selection](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#brushOn__anchor). Could this be the issue?

Comment: @Gordon Thank you for your suggestion but the filtering that `brushOn()` provides is not exactly how I want the charts to be filtered. Is it even possible to select one of the lines on a SeriesChart to filter other charts?

Comment: Oh I get your question now. Sounds like you are trying to do some kind of drilldown interface. dc.js and crossfilter can do that but it's not what they are designed for. You would end up implementing a lot of the behavior by hand and there are probably easier libraries to do it with.

Comment: To answer your specific question, clicking on lines of a series chart is not a built-in behavior. You'd have to implement some event handlers, some custom drawing to display the selection, and use another dimension for filtering, with keys in the series-key space. In the end there isn't much of dc.js left in the solution and you might as well use any interactive charting library.

Comment: I understand now, I'll look into other libraries. Thank you so much for your help!!!